# why is asc+= not reached in Python

Tags: python-3.x

asc+= 1 is not reached why is this:

```
letter =chr(asc)
b = 0
c = 0
for i in range(26):
    bucket.append(None)
    asc = ord(letter)
    for word in aList:
        if word[c] == letter:
            if bucket[b] is None:
                del bucket[b]
                bucket.insert(b, [])
            bucket[b].append(word)
    asc += 1
```

This is not the full program

It's probably so simple but I have been wracking my brain over it for hours. I am trying to create a list of lists and each inner list has words that begin with a certain letter but the variable letter does not change from 'a'

Comment: Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging or post the full code, because the snippet above does not help at all

Answer (score 0):

You aren't reassigning anything to letter within the loop, the asc+=1 is being reached but you aren't doing anything with it.

You find the Unicode integer value of the letter:

```
asc = ord(letter)
```

Then you increment that observation:

```
asc += 1
```

But this doesn't change anything about letter. You're just manipulating a number. You probably meant to include this at the end of the loop:

```
letter = chr(asc)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check if `asc += 1` is being reaching is to add some:

`print asc` at the end of `asc += 1`

Some 'debugging' only to check if it has been reaching that point.

but as glu10 said, you are assigning but you are not using it, then, you are not doing anything with asc.

;) Enjoy